# Drag and drop on Win7 machine to my app

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-7, drag-and-drop

I have a user that is currently running my Winforms app on Win7.  My app allows users to select rows from an open Excel spreadsheet and drag-n-drop them onto the app.  However, this user cannot do the drag-n-drop.  The cursor changes to the "no" cursor (little circle with line through it) and the operation won't complete.

I was researching drag-n-drop and Win7 and everything I found points to UAC and/or UIPI.  I was looking for some solutions and am not sure if any of the below would work:

- If the user logs in as admin (and as a result runs my app as admin) would that allow drag-n-drop to work?
- Does the user need to turn off or change the settings of UAC/UIPI in order to be able to drag-n-drop?

I am not sure what the issue is.  My app usually runs from C:/Documents and Settings/... (C:/Users/... on Win7).  Does where it is running from matter?  Does drag-n-drop not work because the user is not running my app with enough permissions? Are his Excel and my app on different permission levels?  If so, what can be done about that?  Note that even though my app allows users to just drag the file directly, that doesn't work either.

Also, is there any way I can have the user reproduce this issue with other apps?  Are there apps that come with Win7 that he can see the same problem with.  For example, can this be reproduced using Notepad?

Thanks.

Comment: There are restrictions when attempting to drag and drop across security boundaries. If the source and destination are running at the same security level (i.e. both standard user or both elevated) then there should be no problem.

Comment: How are these security levels for apps decided?  I'm assuming that the user is not an admin on his machine.  So if he just runs Excel normally, what security level is used for that?  And if he just double-clicks to run my app, what is my apps security level?  I don't know much about the Win7 security features.  Is all of this decided by settings in UAC?

Comment: You need to get a Windows Vista or Windows 7 machine and try this out for yourself! You can't really get on top of UAC without that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explaining this problem away by UIPI is a *very* long stretch.  It doesn't have anything to do with whether or not the user is logged-in as an admin, that doesn't affect UAC and your program will be running with that same account anyway.  The only way UIPI could kick in to stop a D+D is when *your* program is elevated and Excel is not.

To get yourself elevated requires work and doesn't happen by accident.  You'd have to include a manifest so that the user gets the UAC prompt, you'd know about that.  Or the user would have to change the desktop shortcut and tick the "Run this program as an administrator" option, she's know about that.  While UIPI can be bypassed for Windows messages (ChangeWindowMessageFilter), it cannot for Drag and Drop so if any elevation is going on then your stuck.  The ultimate test is to simply ask the user to put the UAC slider all the way down.

The much more likely scenario is that your DragEnter event handler simply isn't happy with the data it sees and therefore doesn't assign the e.Effect property.  If you can't get a debugger on-site then write a little test program that logs the values of e.Data.GetFormats() plus whatever else you use to check if the drop is acceptable.  And don't forget the obvious: the user simply fumbling the drag somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I don't think it's due to the data that is being dropped.  Using the same build as the user and the same version of Excel, just on WinXP, everything works out fine.  Also, the user is able to open the Excel files using my app's "Import" button instead of dragging and dropping.  That way he just selects it using a standard file browser dialog.  I guess I will ask the user to temporarily set the UAC slider all the way down and see if that has any impact.

Comment: @Flack How can you contemplate developing for Windows without any access to UAC?! I'm inclined to agree with Hans that UIPI is not the most likely culprit.

Comment: @David The app is very old app and there are only a couple of users of it on Win7.  I have access to a Win7 machine but what I found and posted originally was just from a cursory search on Google.  I'm going to do some testing using my Win7 machine and see what I can find out.  Never really had to deal with UAC before since almost all of the existing users are still on XP.  Thanks for the help :)